# Unable to run Snappy player on Beaglebone Black using Yocto Project

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, gnome, openembedded, clutter

My main objective is to run **snappy player** (https://wiki.gnome.org/Snappy) on target machine (**BeagleBone Black**) so, I wrote a recipe for Snappy player(**snappy_1.0.bb**) as below

```
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=686e6cb566fd6382c9fcc7a557bf4544"

SRCREV = "e73fabce4c397b40d490c74f6a6a0de000804f42"
SRC_URI = "git://git.gnome.org/snappy"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "gtk+3 gstreamer1.0 glib-2.0 clutter-1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base libxtst clutter-gst-3.0 clutter-gtk-1.0 libx11 cairo gdk-pixbuf"

# inherit line
inherit pkgconfig autotools

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}/*"
```

Added this recipe name in **local.conf**

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " snappy"
```

The build (*bitbake core-image-sato*) was successful, when I ran "**snappy**" on target(BeagleBone Black) I am getting below **error** response.

```
sh-4.4# snappy
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

(snappy:763): clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize clutter: Unable to initialize the clutter backend: no available drivers found.
```

As per my Understanding in my recipe I have resolved all dependencies for Snappy player (such as clutter, gstreamer, gtk etc.).
I'm unable to figure out why **snappy player** is throwing error?

**Even tried by adding PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/egl ?= "mesa"
in local.conf yet getting the same error.**

Comment: You have a problem with graphical driver I think, maybe it's related to virtual/egl rights, in regard with warnings before?

Comment: By looking at [clutter backend sources](https://github.com/GNOME/clutter/blob/master/clutter/clutter-backend.c#L437), and [clutter manual](https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/running-clutter.html), it seems that Clutter needs OpenGL driver to run. Do you ship it?